# ElasticSearch - define custom letter order for sorting

Tags: java, sorting, elasticsearch, hibernate-search, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm using ElasticSearch 2.4.2 (via HibernateSearch 5.7.1.Final from Java).

I have a problem with string sorting.
The language of my application has diacritics, which have a specific alphabetic
ordering. For example `Ł` goes directly after `L`, `Ó` goes after `O`, etc.
So you are supposed to sort the strings like this:

```
 Dla
 Dła
 Doa
 Dóa
 Dza
 Eza
```

ElasticSearch sorts by typical letters first, and moves all strange
letters to at the end:

```
 Dla
 Doa
 Dza
 Dła
 Dóa
 Eza
```

Can I add a custom letter ordering for ElasticSearch?
Maybe there are some plugins for this?
Do I need to write my own plugin? How do I start?

I found a [plugin](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/plugins/analysis-stempel/) for Polish language for ElasticSearch,
but as I understand it is for analysing, and analysing is not a solution
in my case, because it will ignore diacritics and leave words with `L` and `Ł` mixed:

```
 Dla
 Dłb
 Dlc
```

This would sometimes be acceptable, but is not acceptable in my specific usecase.

I will be grateful for any remarks on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used it, but there is a plugin that could fit your needs: the [ICU collation plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.3/analysis-icu-collation.html).

You will have to use the `icu_collation` token filter, which will turns the tokens into collation keys. For that reason you will need to use a separate `@Field` (e.g. `myField_sort`) in Hibernate Search.

You can assign a specific analyzer to your field with `@Field(name = "myField_sort", analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "myCollationAnalyzer"))`, and define this analyzer (type, parameters) with something like that on one of your entities:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@AnalyzerDef(
    name = "myCollationAnalyzer",
    filters = {
        @TokenFilterDef(
            name = "polish_collation",
            factory = ElasticsearchTokenFilterFactory.class,
            params = {
                @Parameter(name = "type", value = "'icu_collation'"),
                @Parameter(name = "language", value = "'pl'")
            }
        )
    }
)
public class MyEntity {
```

See the documentation for more information: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_custom_analyzers

It's admittedly a bit clumsy right now, but analyzer configuration will get a bit cleaner in the next Hibernate Search version with [normalizers and analyzer definition providers](http://in.relation.to/2017/06/13/hibernate-search-5-8-0-Beta3/).

Note: as usual, your field will need to be declared as sortable (`@SortableField(forField = "myField_sort")`).